# Javascript appendChild()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I am trying to appendChild() two consecutive div's but what I am expecting as result is for them to be side by side, but they are one on top of the other like so:

```
1st div
2nd div
```

instead of 1st div 2nd div

```
var addBudContainer = document.createElement("div");
addBudContainer.id = "addBudContainer";

var addBudBtn = document.createElement("div");
addBudBtn.className = "addBud";

var addBudBtnName = document.createElement("a");
addBudBtnName.className = "btn-addBud";
addBudBtnName.setAttribute("href","#");

addBudBtn.appendChild(addBudBtnName);

var addBudTxt = document.createElement("input");
addBudTxt.id="addBudTxt";
addBudTxt.type="text";
addBudTxt.defaultValue="Enter buddy name";
//txt box effects   
addBudTxt.onfocus = function(){if(replyTxt.value==replyTxt.defaultValue) replyTxt.value='';};
addBudTxt.onblur= function(){if(replyTxt.value=='') replyTxt.value=replyTxt.defaultValue;};

addBudContainer.appendChild(addBudBtn);
addBudContainer.appendChild(addBudTxt);
```

Comment: How about showing some actual code? We're not (very) psychic.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `<div>` elements are "block" elements. In simple terms, this means that a `<div>` will be on its own line (or lines) within its parent element.

`<span>` elements by default are "inline", which might be what you want to use. Inline elements don't push their sibling elements onto other lines.

If you want to override this behavior, you can using CSS.

```
/* This assumes the parent element of your divs has 'some_class' as its class */
.some_class > div {
  display: inline;
}
```

Edit: I added the optional separator semicolon after `display: inline`.

Comment: @Closure Why not `display:inline-block` or `float`?

Comment: @Sime Vidas: `inline-block` is not fully supported across all browsers. IE is particularly bad.

Comment: @Alastair Let's not drag other browsers into this. IE6 and IE7 are the only browsers that don't support it.

Comment: @Matt One can leave out the semi colon on the last property declaration

Comment: @Šime: I didn't know that. Even if it's true, that sounds like an awful practice, that [not even the YUI minifier uses](http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css)...

Comment: There are CSS hacks that usually work for browsers that don't support `inline-block`.

Comment: @Matt The spec states that the semi colon's purpose is to separate property declarations, which means that semi colons are expected only between two declarations. If you place a semi colon on the last declaration, then that semi colon is parsed as an empty declaration. Read here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#rule-sets

Comment: @Šime: well I'll be. I've never seen that before, but you're definitely right.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't use `inline-block` because was trying to keep things very simple. I'm still not positive I interpreted his problem correctly.

Comment: @Sime This is a very old discussion but I am unable to locate the part in your source where it says "If you place a semi colon on the last declaration, then that semi colon is parsed as an empty declaration." Can you please help me narrow it down some more? I understand it is optional but I cannot find that information you stated in the spec or in a Google search.

Comment: @RKS What I've written there is not correct. The spec states that a semi-colon is a separator of declarations. Therefore, a semi-colon must be both preceded and followed by a declaration. If a semi-colon is followed by a closing curly brace, e.g. `#foo { color: red; }`, it may seem that there is no declaration to the right of the semi-colon. However, the spec states that a declaration is "*either empty or consists of...*". This "empty declaration" can be applied in the example above. So, the semicolon separates the declaration `color: red`, and an empty declaration.

Comment: @Sime Ok. I was just wondering if I was missing it there. Honestly, it seems like you're assuming that's the case. No where in the spec does it say this is the case and no where else on the Internet for that matter. I truly think that if that were true it would be mentioned somewhere. It's true that it say it is a separator but for all we know it registers a semi-colon followed by a brace as the end and not inserting an empty declaration as you suggest.

Comment: @RKS What makes you think that empty declarations should be inserted somewhere? It makes more sense to just discard them. *** The spec doesn't define what an empty declaration is. I reason that an empty declaration is the absence of an declaration in positions where a declaration is expected but doesn't appear, i.e. between `;`, and `}`, and between two consecutive `;`. For instance, this, `#foo { width:1em; ;;;;; height:1em }`, is [valid CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). My interpretation of the spec provides an explanation why that code is valid.

Comment: I don't think empty declarations should be inserted. Up until your very last comment, that's what you have stated is happening. The Spec also DOES define what an empty declaration is as selector { } but does not ever say there is an empty declaration between ; } nor should there be.

Comment: @RKS I misunderstood your previous comment. By "*inserting*" I thought you meant a web-browser inserting an empty declaration into the `style` object of a DOM element, i.e. a web-browser actively using that empty declaration. I still stand behind my interpretation that there is an empty declaration in `;}`.

Comment: @RKS Where does the spec define an empty declaration? Btw, in `selector {}`, an empty declaration is not applied, since a declaration block can be empty: "*A declaration block starts with a left curly brace ({) and ends with the matching right curly brace (}). In between there must be a list of zero or more semicolon-separated (;) declarations.*"

Comment: @Sime That's fine if that's your interpretation. I just wanted to find out if that was in the spec or not. You did state it very matter of fact-ly before so I would preface your statement next time. But now that we have determined that, it would probably be best to move this to chat if there is anything else you would like to add. I simply just wanted to get down to the bottom of what the spec says and what you're interpreting. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @RKS I'm actually in the process of writing a separate question to determine whether or not my interpretation is accurate. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You may have better results with `<span>` instead of `<div>` if you want the elements to be laid out in-line rather than as separate blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the "float: left" CSS property to the DIVs, which will cause them to stack up side by side on the left until they've filled up the available width of the enclosing element.